# How to verify a signature in ink! contracts

Tags: ink

I'm trying to create a contract that verifies the signature in a contract function. I wasn't able to find anything in the examples or in the docs.

Is it possible to send a signature to an ink! contract and verify it in its methods?

Comment: What type of signature are you looking to verify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment `contract-pallet` allows you only to verify ECDSA signatures. In ink! you can use [ink_env::ecdsa_recover](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/env/src/api.rs#L493) to do that.

Comment: You can add more signature verification by `ChainExtension`. Check our example here: https://github.com/Phala-Network/phala-blockchain/blob/f3798d2d882f3621d20d7fd3581c138f3e3328b5/crates/pink/src/runtime/extension.rs#L179-L190